# How to set groups by the percentiles of whole sample?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas, and I want to figure out how to group values based on sample quantiles.

For example, I have a dataframe with a column `a`.

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('a'))`

Then what I want to do is to divide the values in `a` into 10 different group by their deciles, and named the label of their group in a column `b`.

Which means in the new column:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | 2 | group 1 |
| 30 | 3 | group 1 |
| 94 | 3 | group 1 |
| 92 | 3 | group 1 |
| 63 | 3 | group 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 47 | 92 | group 10 |
| 58 | 98 | group 10 |
| 66 | 99 | group 10 |
| 73 | 99 | group 10 |
| 24 | 100 | group 10 |

Is that possible?

Now what I do is get the deciles of `a` first as `df2`, then merge the `df2` to the existing `df`. A row is like

|  | a | decile 1 | decile 2 | ... | decile 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5.5 | 18 | ... | 100 |

And get their group by compare them with deciles by a lot of **if else condition**. It is ok for like quartiles, but almost impossible for like percentiles.

I hope I explain my questions clearly enough. If there is any misleading expression, please let me know.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you explain more `Now what I do is get the deciles of a first as df2, then merge the df2 to the existing df. A row is like` ?

Comment: @jezrael Of course. I generate an another dataframe of the deciles information of `df`. In detial, I calculate their deciles by functions like `np.nanpercentile(df['a'], 10)`, and save these 10 deciles (from`np.nanpercentile(df['a'], 10)` to `np.nanpercentile(df['a'], 100)` ) as a dataframe `df2`. Then I concat these to each row of my `df`. Each row will have columns `['a', 'decile1', 'decile2',...,'decile10']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part answer is subtract 1 with integer division by `10` and add `1` for start groups from `1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,101)})

df['b'] = 'group ' + (df.a.sub(1) // 10 + 1).astype(str)
print(df)
      a         b
0     1   group 1
1     2   group 1
2     3   group 1
3     4   group 1
4     5   group 1
..  ...       ...
95   96  group 10
96   97  group 10
97   98  group 10
98   99  group 10
99  100  group 10
```

EDIT: For deciles use [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
df['b'] = pd.qcut(df.a, 10, labels=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But what I really want to do is to treat data without specific orders. I will edit my example data generating process to better express my curiosity.

Comment: @Learner_Lee - Not understand, do you need first group is first 10 rows, next group next 10 rows? Or something else?

Comment: Forgive me for my poor expression. Let me explain it in this way: Suppose now I have a series of people's age (column `a`). Then I want to divide them into four groups according to quartiles of the whole series. (min, 25%, median, 75%, max). For example, Aaron is 18 years old, which is between the the first quantile and median of the data sample. Then I want to label Aaron as `group 2` in column `b`. Do I make this question easier to understand? Anyway, thanks a lot for your attention and patience!

Comment: @Learner_Lee - So need [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) ?

Comment: @Learner_Lee - `df['b'] = pd.qcut(df.a, 10, labels=False)` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I need. Such an easy and efficient method!